# How to find top N minimum values from the DataFrame, Python-3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have below Dataframe with Field 'Age', Needs find to top 3 minimum age from the DataFrame

```
DF = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'Name':['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'], 'Age':[18, 45, 35, 70, 23, 24, 50, 65, 18, 23]})

DF['Age'].min()
```

Want top two Age i.e 18, 23 in List, How to achieve this?

Note: DataFrame - DF Contains Age Duplicates i.e 18 & 23 repeated twice, need unique values.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can make use of [**`nsmallest(..)`** [pandas-doc]](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest.html#pandas.DataFrame.nsmallest):

```
df.nsmallest(2, 'Age')
```

For the given sample data, this gives us:

```
>>> df.nsmallest(2, 'Age')
  Name  Age
0    A   18
4    E   23
```

Or if you only need the value of the `Age` column:

```
>>> df['Age'].nsmallest(2)
0    18
4    23
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

or you can wrap it in a list:

```
>>> df['Age'].nsmallest(2).to_list()
[18, 23]
```

You can obtain the *n* smallest *unique* values, by first constructing a `Series` with unique values:

```
>>> pd.Series(df['Age'].unique()).nsmallest(2)
0    18
4    23
dtype: int64
>>> df['Age'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(2)
0    18
4    23
Name: Age, dtype: int64
```

Comment: @SPy: you can make use of `df['Age'].nsmallest(2)` as well :)

Answer (score 3):

The right thing is to use `nsmallest`, here I show another way: [`DataFrame.sort_values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) + [`DataFrame.head`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.head.html)

```
df['Age'].sort_values().head(2).tolist()
#[18, 23]
```

---

**UPDATED**

If there are **duplicates**, we could use [`Series.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.drop_duplicates.html) previously:

```
df['Age'].drop_duplicates().nsmallest(2).tolist()
#df['Age'].drop_duplicates().sort_values().head(2).tolist()
#[18, 23]
```

or [`np.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sort.html) + [`np.unique`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html)

```
[*np.sort(df['Age'].unique())[:2]]
#[18, 23]
```